# search data from android app to website and fetch results to android

Tags: android

I have an android app and when i click on a button i want to search something from a website and then i want to fetch the results on the app, but i am so confused and i don't know how to do that. 
For example, when i click on search button (pic1) i want to search in background some string (pic2) and the bring the result back to the app (pic3 - red square).

[image]

[image]

[image]
The only thing that i managed to do is bring text from the website (https://world.openfoodfacts.org/).

```
package com.example.owner.foodal11_2.activity;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.owner.foodal11_2.R;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.IOException;


/**
 * Created by Owner on 17/7/2018.
 */

public class GetDataFromWebsite extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);
        Button but= (Button)findViewById(R.id.getRes);
        but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new doit().execute();

            }
        });
        }

    public class doit extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
String words;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            try {
                Document doc= Jsoup.connect("https://world.openfoodfacts.org/").get();

            words=doc.text();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            text.setText(words);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `world.openfoodfacts.org`[`JSON API`](https://world.openfoodfacts.org/data) instead of parsing `html` content:

```
public class FetchAllergensTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        final String barcode = strings[0];
        @Nullable
        String allergens = null;
        try {
            final String jsonStr = Jsoup.connect(
                    "https://world.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/" + barcode + ".json")
                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                    .execute()
                    .body();

            final JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            if (jsonObj.has("product")) {
                JSONObject productNode = jsonObj.getJSONObject("product");
                allergens = productNode.getString("allergens");
            }
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return allergens;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(@Nullable String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // setText(result);
    }
}
```

...

```
new FetchAllergensTask().execute("5200334220012");
```

Comment: how to show result in Textview?
I add  `new FetchAllergensTask().execute("5200334220012");`  on clickListener but it doesn's show anything. I try to declare textview in FetchAllergens class but show errors.

Comment: `onPostExecute()` receives the result. You should call the setText() method of your TextView to the `onPostExecute()` method

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the string you wanna search in web site by use Jsoup like example:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com/login.php")
.data("username", "myUsername", "password", "myPassword")
.method(Method.POST)
.execute();
```

Document doc = res.parse();
Then parse the data you need from this.